# How to italicize a self-reference?

Tags: writing, italics

Suppose I am writing a book. If I were to say, mentioned the title of the book in the introduction; would it be italicized?

Now suppose I am writing a paper; what then?

Thanks!

### Edit

I am writing a paper on my own basis. I am asking specifically on whether or not I should italicize the title of my paper/book when referencing inside the paper/book.

Comment: Treat it as you would a book written by anyone else.

Comment: This is hugely unclear: do you mean "Should I italicise the title of my own paper when I refer to it"? (Whatever the answer, please edit rather than putting information in comments). Also, is this really a question about English rather than style? If the latter, then "consult the stylebook favoured in your organization, or choose your preferred one".

Comment: @TimLymington Any suggestions for a good stylebook?

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a   Second::

global.oup.com/uk/academic/authors/AuthorGuidelinesMain/  That's two styles of style-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The normal convention is "italicise the titles of books" not "italicise the titles of other books". It's the title of a book, you italicise it.

If nothing else, it can be particularly useful if perhaps the title were the same as the subject (one might expect a non-fiction book called *Elephants* to mention elephants more often than most books do, and so italicising would be useful to distinguish from when the author or a foreword contributor was talking about *Elephants* from when they were talking about elephants) or if the title of an anthology were the same as one of its parts (so if a collection of short stories included a story called "once upon a time" and was itself called *Once upon a Time*). Or indeed perhaps even both (hmm, if I ever publish a collection maybe I'll include my story "Scary Stories" and call it *Scary Stories* just so I can have an introduction that talks about how *Scary Stories* includes "Scary Stories" and also some scary stories).

Comment: And what about a paper?

Comment: Italicised or in quotation marks, as per what your style guide would have you do with any other paper.

Answer (score 1):

If you mention the title of the book in your introduction (or anywhere except that one important time on the title page!), yes, you would italicize it:

> Introduction
>
> So:  why does the world need yet another edition of *My Magnificent Book*?  It's because in earlier editions, *My Magnificent Book*...

...because it's a book, and book titles are italicized.

Comment: Yes, but what if I am talking about a paper?

Comment: Same thing as Jon said below:  treat it the way you would a paper.  (Which, by the way, ordinarily is to put it in quotation marks.)